# Install Qutip on Mac os x 10.10 via MacPorts

Tags: osx-yosemite, macports, qutip

I am not sure whether i can ask this question here.

I tried to install QuTips on my mac osx 10.10. Am following these two documentation for installation [Qutip](http://qutip.org/docs/3.1.0/installation.html) and [MacPorts](http://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.source). Now am struggle to install gcc49.

When i execute this command `sudo port install py34-scipy` I got the following error

```
    Admins-iMac-2:base admin$ sudo port install py27-scipy
--->  Computing dependencies for py27-scipy
The following dependencies will be installed: 
 gcc49
 py27-numpy
 swig
 swig-python
Continue? [Y/n]: y
--->  Building gcc49
Error: Failed to build gcc49: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/gcc49/main.log for details.
Error: Follow http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets to report a bug.
Error: Processing of port py27-scipy failed
Admins-iMac-2:base admin$ sudo port install py34-numpy
--->  Computing dependencies for py34-numpy
The following dependencies will be installed:  gcc49
Continue? [Y/n]: y
--->  Building gcc49
Error: Failed to build gcc49: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/gcc49/main.log for details.
Error: Follow http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets to report a bug.
Error: Processing of port py34-numpy failed
Admins-iMac-2:base admin$ vi /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/gcc49/main.log
Admins-iMac-2:base admin$
```

I go and look for `main.log` file. At the end of this file i got below errors

```
:info:build gcc/vtable-verify.o differs
:info:build make[2]: *** [compare] Error 1
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/gcc49/work/build'
:info:build make[1]: *** [stage3-bubble] Error 2
:info:build make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/gcc49/work/build'
:info:build make: *** [bootstrap] Error 2
:info:build make: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/gcc49/work/build'
:info:build Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/gcc49/work/build" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w bootstrap
:info:build Exit code: 2
:error:build Failed to build gcc49: command execution failed
:debug:build Error code: CHILDSTATUS 2595 2
:debug:build Backtrace: command execution failed
:debug:build     while executing
:debug:build "system {*}$notty {*}$nice $fullcmdstring"
:debug:build     invoked from within
:debug:build "command_exec build"
:debug:build     (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
:debug:build     invoked from within
:debug:build "$procedure $targetname"
:debug:build Registry error: gcc49 not registered as installed & active.
:debug:build     invoked from within
:debug:build "registry_active $subport"
:debug:build     invoked from within
:debug:build "$workername eval registry_active \$subport"
:error:build See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/gcc49/main.log for details.
```

Am not familiar with this. I cannot complete installation without this `gcc49`. Alternatively i install gcc48, but dosen't work for me. Every time it automatically tried ti install gcc49.

Anybody have any suggestion, it will be really appreciated.

Comment: You were right in pasting the log file, but the relevant error output is actually missing from it because it happened before your cutoff. You'll have to pastbin the full main.log somewhere if you want an answer. You can also try the MacPorts user mailing list for support: https://www.macports.org/contact.php#Lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer my question

run `sudo port clean gcc49`, then try again